# How to skip a row and move to the next and click on certain button

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to skip one row and click a button on the next one. Everytime, it goes back to the row I want to skip and clicks. How do I click on the next row?

This is what my code looks like:

```
List<Web Element>  mod=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='awardTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span"))
for(WebElement md : mod){
   if(md.getAttribute("title")){
      continue;
   }
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='awardTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span")).click();
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
List<Web Element>  mod=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='awardTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span"))
for(WebElement md : mod){
   if(md.getAttribute("title")){
      continue;
   }
   md.click();
   break;
}
```

In your code, after checkinig title you are again finding elements using xpath which will again fetch same data which you dont want to click.